# Graph with adjacency matrix in C

Tags: c, graph-algorithm, adjacency-matrix

I have this `struct`:

```
struct graph {
    int** adj; /**< Adjacency matrix. */
    int n; /**< Number of nodes in graph. */
};
```

and I have to create a void graph into this function:

```
struct graph *graph_create(int nodes) {
  //To implement
}
```

How can I create a matrix using that double pointer `int** adj`?

Comment: Please show us what you have tried so far.

Comment: Graph struct first element is `int **adj` just only a pointer to pointer integer that points to first elements of your matrix. First use `malloc()` to allocate memory for that.

Comment: Your function get number of nodes in graph, implements that graph in form of an adjacency matrix, then return that as `struct  graph`

Comment: If in the create function I define struct graph *graph, malloc is graph->adj=(int**)malloc(sizeof(int*)*n)?

Comment: Do either of the answers answer your question? you should choose one as the correct solution, or ask a question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the way to define a matrix with `malloc()` 
that i catch from [GeeksForGeeks](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/dynamically-allocate-2d-array-c/) with some edition.

**2D integer Matrix with `int **` and `malloc()`**

```
int r = 3, c = 4, i, j, count;

//arr[r][c]
int **arr = (int **)malloc(r * sizeof(int *));

for (i=0; i<r; i++){
    *(arr +i) = (int *)malloc(c * sizeof(int));
    //arr[i] = (int *)malloc(c * sizeof(int));
}

// Note that arr[i][j] is same as *(*(arr+i)+j)
count = 0;
for (i = 0; i <  r; i++)//3
    for (j = 0; j < c; j++)//4
        arr[i][j] = ++count;  // OR *(*(arr+i)+j) = ++count

for (i = 0; i <  r; i++){
    printf("\n");
    for (j = 0; j < c; j++){
        printf("%d ", arr[i][j]);
    }
}
```

And we can put these code inside `graph_create(int nodes)` function.

**Code**

```
struct graph {
    int** adj; /**< Adjacency matrix. */
    int n; /**< Number of nodes in graph. */
}G;


struct graph *graph_create(int nodes) {

    struct graph * tmp = &G;
    int r = nodes, c = nodes, i, j, count;

    //arr[r][c]
    G.adj = (int **)malloc(r * sizeof(int *));

    for (i=0; i<r; i++){
         *(G.adj + i) = (int *)malloc(c * sizeof(int));
         //arr[i] = (int *)malloc(c * sizeof(int));
    }


    count = 0;
    for (i = 0; i <  r; i++)//3
      for (j = 0; j < c; j++)//4
         G.adj[i][j] = ++count;  // OR *(*(arr+i)+j) = ++count

    for (i = 0; i <  r; i++){
        printf("\n");
        for (j = 0; j < c; j++){
            printf("%d ", G.adj[i][j]);
        }
    }

    return tmp;

}



int main()
{


    struct graph * d = graph_create(5);

    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}
```

We know the adjacency Matrix of a graph have n*n dimension.
for that we use nodes as row and column.

**Edit**

For secure working with `malloc()` function we must free the memory locations that is reserved by `malloc()`, by calling `free()` with these blocks. (similar to  [Mobius](https://stackoverflow.com/users/440166/mobius) answer)

just before `return 0;` statement in `main()` call this:

`free ((*d).adj);`

Required header files:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h> // for** malloc()**, **free()**
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to allocate a matrix, you need to allocate room for the actual matrix data (of size `width * height * sizeof(int)`).

In your setup with an `int**` matrix, you also need to allocate an array of pointers, which will point to the beginning of each row, if you wanted to avoid this, you could simply compute the offset by doing something like `size_t offset = row * width + column`.

To allocate the pointers, we need `height * sizeof(int*)` bytes.

finally you will need to assign the row pointers in your array.

All together the code should look about like this:

```
int ** allocate_matrix(size_t width, size_t height){
    int *  values = malloc(height * width * sizeof(int));
    int ** rows   = malloc(height * sizeof(int*));

    size_t i;
    for (i = 0; i < height; i++) {
        size_t offset = i * width;
        rows[i] = &values[offset];
    }

    return rows;
}

// the returned matrix can me indexed like `matrix[row][column]`
```

In order to free our memory pointed to by `adj`:

```
void free_matrix(int ** rows) {
    // this points to the beginning of our region of memory for values;
    int * values = rows[0]; 

    free(values);
    free(rows);
}
```

Comment: @pipox does this answer your question?